# Python TCP Socket losing data in recv [acting weird]

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I wrote a simplistic socket client for reading data in Python 3.4

The problem I'm having is that when the server sends a small amount of data (around `1000`) bytes, it will read it perfectly but when a large chunk of data is being handled around (`9500` bytes) it will only give me a small chunk of data (like `1100-ish` chunks). I can't seem to figure out why its behaving so erratically  when handling the huge amount of data. I know that my data is not larger than `ssize_t` maximum of `32767`.

It works perfectly when handling small data and completely turns 180 and behaves differently when handling a huge amount of data. I know that this is not a problem in the TCP server because I tested it with a PHP TCP client and it worked perfectly when handling the huge amount of data.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import socket
import json

# Written in Python 3.4.

class SocketClient:

    def __init__(self, host, port, format, timeout = None):
        # Constructor
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.format = format
        self.timeout = timeout

        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def send(self, firstname, lastname, parameters = [], format = 'json'):
        if self.socket is not None:
            self.socket.connect((self.host, self.port))

            data = {}
            data['firstname'] = firstname
            data['lastname'] = lastname
            data['parameters'] = parameters
            data['format'] = format

            self.socket.send(bytes(json.dumps(data), "utf-8"))

            result = self.socket.recv(32767)
            result = result.decode()

            return result

    def shutdown(self):
        if socket is not None:
            self.socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            self.socket.close()


if __name__ == __main__:
    client = SocketClient("127.0.0.1", 8080, 'json')
    response = client.send('foo', 'bar', ['foobar'])
    print(response)
    client.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP is a streaming protocol. Data is delivered in junks of bytes, where the length is determined by many factors. One is, that internal buffers are limited to some thousand bytes. You never can read 32767 bytes at once.
The only guarantee with `recv` is, that you get at least 1 byte and at most the number of bytes you say. Your code have to cope with this, that means, you have to do more than one `recv` call until you have the amount of bytes you need. That means on the other side, a protocol that don't have end-of-message indicators or a length encoded is badly broken. In your case: you have to parse the json byte stream until a valid json expression is sent. But what about `1245.6`? Is it finished after receiving `1` or `12` or ...?
To repair your protocol, simply send some length information with your json data.

For sending you should use `sendall` instead of `send`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `recv_into(buffer[, nbytes[, flags]])` method:

```
def readReliably(s,n):
    buf = bytearray(n)
    view = memoryview(buf)
    sz = 0
    while sz < n:
        k = s.recv_into(view[sz:],n-sz)
        sz += k
    # print 'readReliably()',sz
    return sz,buf

def writeReliably(s,buf,n):
    sz = 0
    while sz < n:
        k = s.send(buf[sz:],n-sz)
        sz += k
    # obj = s.makefile(mode='w')
    # obj.flush()
    # print 'writeReliably()',sz
    return sz
```

See the full example at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55446223/966789

```
while True:
  sk,skfrom = s.accept()
  sz,buf = io.readReliably(sk,4)
  a = struct.unpack("4B",buf)
  print repr(a)
  # ...
  io.writeReliably(sk,struct.pack("4B",*[0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04]))
```

Answer (score 0):

That is how recv works in more than one language... https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv

Comment: I understand that... but why would it behave so differently when handling different sizes of data when you give a large buffer?

Comment: You do not give it a large buffer. You just ask the system to read at most that much.

Comment: I'm telling it to read at most `32767` but the actual data that is to be read is smaller than `32767`. Its around `10000` but it not reading it completely, it is cut off. When I am reading data around `2000` it works. I have ran several tests and confirmed its not the actual TCP server problem. It is just in Python causing it to behave so weird.

Comment: This answer tells us little, and tommyo's your comment us unhelpful too.