# Python socket module: Recv() data response cut off

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, networking, tcp

## **Explanation**

I'm currently trying to control a smart power strip using a python script. To accomplish this, I'm using a TCP connection with the socket module. Around 75% of the time, I get the response/data I was looking for and everything works perfectly. However, around 25% of the time, the response is cut off at the exact same length, 1024 bytes. This doesn't make any sense to me, as my buffer size is actually set to 2048 bytes. The speed at which I wait in between using recv() doesn't seem to effect/cause this either. Altough TCP is a stream of bytes, is it still possible that this could have to do with packet fragmentation?

## **Code**

**Main Code**

```
ip='192.168.0.62'
port=9999

sock_tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock_tcp.connect((ip, port))
sock_tcp.send(encrypt('{"system":{"get_sysinfo":{}}}'))
data = sock_tcp.recv(2048)
sock_tcp.close()
print len(data) #On succesful runs output is 1221, on unsuccesful runs it is 1024
rec = decrypt(data[4:])
print str(rec) #See output below
```

**Encrypt Function**

```
def encrypt(string):
    key = 171
    result = pack('>I', len(string))
    for i in string:
        a = key ^ ord(i)
        key = a
        result += chr(a)
    return result
```

**Decrypt Function**

```
def decrypt(string):
    key = 171
    result = ""
    for i in string:
        a = key ^ ord(i)
        key = ord(i)
        result += chr(a)
    return result
```

## **Output**

The string itself that I recieve. It's most likeley not relevant, but I thought I would include it anyway. This is value of the variable rec.

**Desired and regular output**

Full desired output

> {"system":{"get_sysinfo":{"sw_ver":"1.0.6 Build 180627
>   Rel.081000","hw_ver":"1.0","model":"HS300(US)","deviceId":"80067B24A755F99C4D6C1807455E09F91AB7B2AA","oemId":"5C9E6254BEBAED63B2B6102966D24C17","hwId":"34C41AA028022D0CCEA5E678E8547C54","rssi":-60,"longitude_i":-1222955,"latitude_i":379078,"alias":"TP-LINK_Power
>   Strip_4F01","mic_type":"IOT.SMARTPLUGSWITCH","feature":"TIM:ENE","mac":"B0:BE:76:12:4F:01","updating":0,"led_off":0,"children":[{"id":"80067B24A755F99C4D6C1807455E09F91AB7B2AA00","state":0,"alias":"CezHeat","on_time":0,"next_action":{"type":-1}},{"id":"80067B24A755F99C4D6C1807455E09F91AB7B2AA01","state":1,"alias":"CezUVB","on_time":191208,"next_action":{"type":-1}},{"id":"80067B24A755F99C4D6C1807455E09F91AB7B2AA02","state":1,"alias":"CyanHeat","on_time":191208,"next_action":{"type":-1}},{"id":"80067B24A755F99C4D6C1807455E09F91AB7B2AA03","state":1,"alias":"ZanderHeat","on_time":191208,"next_action":{"type":-1}},{"id":"80067B24A755F99C4D6C1807455E09F91AB7B2AA04","state":1,"alias":"CairoHeat","on_time":191208,"next_action":{"type":-1}},{"id":"80067B24A755F99C4D6C1807455E09F91AB7B2AA05","state":1,"alias":"KodaMister","on_time":191208,"next_action":{"type":-1}}],"child_num":6,"err_code":0}}}

**Abnormal and rarer output**

Cut off output

> {"system":{"get_sysinfo":{"sw_ver":"1.0.6 Build 180627
>   Rel.081000","hw_ver":"1.0","model":"HS300(US)","deviceId":"80067B24A755F99C4D6C1807455E09F91AB7B2AA","oemId":"5C9E6254BEBAED63B2B6102966D24C17","hwId":"34C41AA028022D0CCEA5E678E8547C54","rssi":-59,"longitude_i":-1222955,"latitude_i":379078,"alias":"TP-LINK_Power
>   Strip_4F01","mic_type":"IOT.SMARTPLUGSWITCH","feature":"TIM:ENE","mac":"B0:BE:76:12:4F:01","updating":0,"led_off":0,"children":[{"id":"80067B24A755F99C4D6C1807455E09F91AB7B2AA00","state":0,"alias":"CezHeat","on_time":0,"next_action":{"type":-1}},{"id":"80067B24A755F99C4D6C1807455E09F91AB7B2AA01","state":1,"alias":"CezUVB","on_time":191207,"next_action":{"type":-1}},{"id":"80067B24A755F99C4D6C1807455E09F91AB7B2AA02","state":1,"alias":"CyanHeat","on_time":191207,"next_action":{"type":-1}},{"id":"80067B24A755F99C4D6C1807455E09F91AB7B2AA03","state":1,"alias":"ZanderHeat","on_time":191207,"next_action":{"type":-1}},{"id":"80067B24A755F99C4D6C1807455E09F91AB7B2AA04","state":1,"alias":"CairoHeat","on

## **Conclusion**

If anyone could provide me with a solution or explanation as to why the output/stream gets cut off, it would be much appreciated. I used a lot of the code from this open source [module](https://github.com/softScheck/tplink-smartplug/blob/master/tplink_smartplug.py). I'm also looking to understand more of how this all works, so if you could explain a bit more I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Personally I just add a length header before sending. I read that [it's redundant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62169403/large-byte-array-any-benefit-of-storing-length-within-the-byte-array), but eh, it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv), the bufsize argument only specifies the maximum amount of data to be read:

> socket.recv(bufsize[, flags])
>   Receive data from the socket. The return
>   value is a bytes object representing the data received. **The maximum
>   amount of data to be received at once is specified by bufsize**. See the
>   Unix manual page recv(2) for the meaning of the optional argument
>   flags; it defaults to zero.

To ensure full data transfer a function like this can be used, which waits for the end of the socket connection (indicated by and empty string returned from recv):

```
def recv_all(connection):
    """
    Function for all data

    :param connection: socket connection
    :return: received data
    """
    data = list()
    while True:
        data.append(connection.recv(2048))
        if not data[-1]:
            return b''.join(data)
```

Another example that might fit your application better could be to wait for a fixed message size (1221 as indicated by your question):

```
def recv_message(connection):
    data = list()
    transferred_bytes= 0
    while transferred_bytes < 1221:
        data.append(connection.recv(min(1221-transferred_bytes, 2048)))
        if not data[-1]:
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
        transferred_bytes += len(data[-1])
    return b''.join(data)
```

Comment: As indicated by @SergeBallesta, it is better to look for framing in the higher level protocol (in this case balanced { and }) than to assume the message is a fixed size.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works; however it takes about 30 seconds each time to finish the entire function (usually takes half a second with the original code.)  Is the smart plug itself to blame for how it handles TCP connections?

Comment: Yes, the (first) code waits for the plug to "hang up the call" before returning the data. If the plug doesn't hang up it will wait for more data.

Comment: @MarcoC Some research into the protocol used by your plug seems to suggest that the first 4 bytes (`data[:4]`) that are thrown away actually contains the message length (minus the 4 bytes for the length) so ´struct.unpack(">I", data[:4])[0] + 4´ should be the length that can be used with code 2

Answer (score 2):

This is only a complement to SimonF's answer. The cause of the problem is indeed that TCP is a stream protocol, so packets can be fragmented or re-assembled at any state: sender TCP/IP stack, network equipments, receiver TCP/IP stack - I include the user layer library in the TCP/IP stack here for simplification.

That is the reason why, you should always use a higher level protocol above TCP to be able to split the stream in *sensible* messages. Here you could note that the end of a message is `'}}}'`, so you could concatenate the input in a buffer until you find that pattern:

```
def recv_until(c, guard):
    """Receive data from a socket until guard if found on input"""
    guard_sz = len(guard) - 1
    data = b''
    sz = 0
    while True:
        buffer = c.recv(1024)      # read by chuncks of size 1024 (change value to your needs)
        got = len(buffer)
        data += buffer             # concatenate in buffer
        ix = data.find(guard, sz - guard_sz if sz > guard_sz else 0)    # is guard found?
        if ix != -1:
            return (data[:ix + guard_sz + 1],   # return the message, and what could be behind it
                data[ix + guard_sz + 1:])

        sz += got
```

The trick is to considere guard_sz byte from the last chunk, in the case where the guard could be split in two chunks.

Comment: Better to count { and } as you go, and to look for the final } that matches the balancing opening { (as opposed to assuming that the nesting is always 3 deep and assuming that there is no whitespace between the final }s)  (PS: the analysis that this is caused by the fact that TCP is a stream protocol is correct; a TCP read is not guaranteed to fill the buffer and you need to keep reading until you have all the data that you need, as determined by the framing at a higher protocol level)

Answer (score 1):

Marco, please use `recv_into(buffer[, nbytes[, flags]])` method for the socket.

My example for TCP-microserver:

```
import socket
import struct

def readReliably(s,n):
    buf = bytearray(n)
    view = memoryview(buf)
    sz = 0
    while sz < n:
        k = s.recv_into(view[sz:],n-sz)
        sz += k
    # print 'readReliably()',sz
    return sz,buf

def writeReliably(s,buf,n):
    sz = 0
    while sz < n:
        k = s.send(buf[sz:],n-sz)
        sz += k
    # obj = s.makefile(mode='w')
    # obj.flush()
    # print 'writeReliably()',sz
    return sz

# Client
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 23456
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(10)
s.connect((host,port))
# Request
buf = struct.pack("4B",*[0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04])
io.writeReliably(s,buf,4)
# Response
sz,buf = io.readReliably(s,4)
a = struct.unpack("4B",buf)
print repr(a)

# Server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
#s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
#s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(10) # unaccepted connections
while True:
  sk,skfrom = s.accept()
  sz,buf = io.readReliably(sk,4)
  a = struct.unpack("4B",buf)
  print repr(a)
  # ...
  io.writeReliably(sk,struct.pack("4B",*[0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04]))
```

Comment: FYI `NameError: name 'io' is not defined`