# Large byte array - any benefit of storing length within the byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, compression, large-data

#### Q: Is there any benefit of storing the length of a large array within the array itself?

#### Explanation:

Let's say we compress some large binary serialized object by using the GZipStream class of the System.IO.Compression namespace.
The output will be a Base64 string of some compressed byte array.
At some later point the Base64 string gets converted back to a byte array and the data needs to be decompressed.

While compressing the data we create a new byte array with the size of the compressed byte array + 4.
In the first 4 bytes we store the length/size of the compressed byte array and we then BlockCopy the length and the data to the new array. This new array gets converted into a Base64 string.

While decompressing we convert the Base64 string into a byte array.
Now we can extract the length of the actual compressed data by using the BitConverter class which will extract a Int32 from the first 4 bytes.
We then allocate a byte array with the length that we got from the first 4 bytes and let the Stream write the decompressed bytes to the byte array.

I can't image that something like this actually has any benefit at all.
It adds more complexity to the code and more operations need to be executed.
Readability is reduced too.
The BlockCopy operations alone should consume so much resources that this just cannot have a benefit, right?

#### Compression example code:

```cs
byte[] buffer = new byte[0xffff] // Some large binary serialized object
// Compress in-memory.
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    // The actual compression takes place here.
    using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(mem, CompressionMode.Compress, true)) {
        zipStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    // Store compressed byte data here.
    var compressedData = new byte[mem.Length];
    mem.Position = 0;                
    mem.Read(compressedData, 0, compressedData.Length);

    /* Increase the size by 4 to accommadate for an Int32 that
    ** will store the total length of the compressed data. */
    var zipBuffer = new byte[compressedData.Length + 4];
    // Store length of compressedData array in the first 4 bytes.
    Buffer.BlockCopy(compressedData, 0, zipBuffer, 4, compressedData.Length);
    // Store the compressedData array after the first 4 bytes which store the length.
    Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length), 0, zipBuffer, 0, 4);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(zipBuffer);
}
```

#### Decompression example code:

```cs
byte[] zipBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String("some base64 string");
using (var inStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // The length of the array that was stored in the first 4 bytes.
    int dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(zipBuffer, 0);
    // Allocate array with specific size.
    byte[] buffer = new byte[dataLength];

    // Writer data to buffer array.
    inStream.Write(zipBuffer, 4, zipBuffer.Length - 4);                
    inStream.Position = 0;

    // Decompress data.
    using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(inStream, CompressionMode.Decompress)) {
        zipStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    ... code
    ... code 
    ... code
}
```

Comment: `I can't image that something like this actually has any benefit at all.` It can benefit when streams of data are involved. You read the start of the stream - it tells you how many bytes to read until the end of this "block" of data (e.g. variable length string). I believe protobuf works like this, for example, when dealing with `Length-delimited` so you know when this "block" of data ends.

Comment: `mem.Read(compressedData, 0, compressedData.Length);` This line of code worries me. It looks like you _assume_ that if you ask it to read a certain number of bytes then it will do so. That is a dangerous (read: foolish) assumption when dealing with streams. You really should check the return value of that call.

Comment: What you are doing is exactly like a lot of Linux/Unix operating system create structures.  Withe binary data the byte array is proceeded with a length property so when data is moved/sent from one application to another application the receive end of the system know where the data ends.  The receive end of a stream (pipe) does not have the object that contains the byte count.

Comment: Having the lenght in teh Data? You should ask any Network Protocoll if that is a good idea.. The answer is "Yes" for every Frame, Package and DataGram format. If nothing else, just to have a way to avoid buffer overflow attacks with the data.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged the question as C#, wich means .NET, so the question is irrelevant:

The Framework **already** store the length with the Array. It is **how** the array classes do the sanity checks on Indexers. It how it prevents overflow attacks in managed code. That help alone is worth any minor inefficiency (note that the JiT is actually able to prune most of the checks. With a loop for example, it will simply look at the running variable once per loop).

You would have to go all the way into unmanaged code and handling naked pointers to have a hope to get rid of it. But why would you? The difference is so small, it falls under the [speed rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). If it maters, you propably got a realtime programming case. And starting those with .NET was a bad idea.

Comment: Doesn't  really render the question irrelevant? You've just in fact answered the question, A: No, there is no benefit.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood My answer was "it provides buffer overflow protection" and "that is worth any price". If the original heartbeat code had used it, we would never have had heartbleed. I can not stress the importnace of overflow proteciton **strongly enough** And I totally understand why someone pampered with .NET might not get it. | I also asnwered "it only matters if you are doing realtime programming" and "if you are doing realtime programming, .NET was the wrong starting point".

Comment: @Chistopher I had understood the question as: "Is there any use in **manually** storing length meta in the array it's self?" (when using .NET). The answer to which is "no" as per your point "The Framework already store the length with the Array". I don't believe the suggestion is that the framework storing the length is redundant/optional for all the reasons you have explained.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood It sounded like he was transmitting, storing or retreiving the Array. And not using a existing approach like XML or REST, that deal with the issues. At wich point some level of "manually" storing the Size in the stream maters.